# Lua gmatch (what exactly does it do?)

Tags: string, lua

Can someone translate this code for me ? (I'm trying to translate without running it, i don't have a compiler)

for x in somestring:gmatch'.' do

What exactly does gmatch do, and is '.' a special character, or is it just a period? Thanks!

Comment: LUA online: [lua.org](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php),[rextester](http://rextester.com/l/lua_online_compiler), [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/lua), [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online) and etc.

Comment: Your code traverses every character of the string. Yes, `.` is a special character (meaning any char).  Lua characters are always 1-byte.

Comment: there are plenty of online interpreters available if you don't want to install Lua... https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: Thanks everyone, very helpful, and should solve this and future issues!